# $OnChange doesn't trigger when pass object by reference

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

Hey I have the following example which demonstrate a problem which I faced in bigger scale.

I have in my example: 2 components: Parent Component and Child Component.
I have a field of rules which is exist both in child and parent component.
Parent Component send this field(rules field) using bindings('<' one-way binding) to his child component.

The child gets an updated value of rules all the time, the problem is that onChanges event doesn't trigger when I set a new data to current rules field using timeout($timeout).

All works as expected except that onChanges event doesn't not fire when pass object by reference in timeout process(which demonstrate an ajax call).

Can someone explain me why this behavior happens and how do I force onchanges event to get fire when ever I change an object.

Here is the example of my use case:

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.component("parent",{
  template:`ParentCmp-{{$ctrl.rules}}
            child- <child rules="$ctrl.rules"></child>`,
  controller:['$timeout',function($timeout){
    this.$onInit= function(){
      this.rules = { name: "Rule1" , Description: "Description" } ;
      this.updatedRules = { name: "UpdateRule1" , Description: "Update Description" }
      var self = this;
     $timeout(function(){
            self.rules = self.updatedRules;
            console.log("update rules",self.rules);
    },3000);
    }
  }]
});

app.component("child",{
  template:"childCmp-{{$ctrl.rules}}",
  bindings:{
    rules: '<'
  },
  controller:['$timeout',function($timeout){
    this.$onInit= function(){
      //this.rules = {};
    }
    this.$onChange = function(changes){
      console.log("onchange event",changes);
    }
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  
  <parent></parent>
  
</div>
```

Comment: no one can solve the riddle :/?

Comment: Use `onChanges` with an `s`. See [AngularJS $compile Service API Reference - Life-Cycle Hooks](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks).

Comment: I am voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a **simple typographic error**.

Comment: my mistake close this issue

Answer (score 1):

Its typo.It should be [`$onChanges`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)and not `$onChange` in the `child` component

```
this.$onChanges = function(changes){
      console.log("onchange event",changes);
    }
```

Working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/YmEQJhzhu9hmdwAqk7Ac?p=preview)